Проектирование системы сообщений
Никак не могу разобраться, как спроектировать систему сообщений (диалогов). В частности, на уровне СУБД.
Допустим, у нас есть таблицы:

dialogs
dialog_messages
dialog_users

Со временем в таблице dialog_messages, если, например, там установлен INT AUTO_INCREMENT, а у нас идет в эту таблицу активная запись, мы упираемся в лимит INT или BIGINT. Даже несмотря на то, что число кажется каким-то невероятным (что-то около 9 квинтиллионов или около того), мы рано или поздно упремся в этот лимит. Но сначала мы упремся либо в диск, либо в максимальный размер таблицы. Это можно решить партиционированием и шардированием, понятное дело. Но что будет, когда мы достигнем этого значения (9 квинтиллионов сообщений)?
Хорошо, можно использовать UUID или GUID. Тоже, в целом, вариант, но идентификаторы рано или поздно могут совпасть. Я понимаю, что это настолько маловероятное событие (что-то около 1 из 2,71 x 10 в 18 степени, если мы говорим про UUID v4 122 бита), но всё же не нулевая. А проверять на каждое новое сообщение - не совпадает ли оно с уже имеющимися идентификаторами, как будто такая себе затея.
Можно, конечно, использовать MongoDB (или PostgreSQL с JSONB) и каким-то образом складывать это туда, но я пока не понимаю в каком направлении хотя бы начать смотреть, не то, что двигаться. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто реализовывал подобное, как вы решали такие задачи и с какими сложностями сталкивались в процессе реализации и в каком направлении стоит вообще двигаться делая что-то подобное, чтобы при росте количества сообщений не было головной боли или хотя бы минимизировать ее на начальном этапе?

«мы рано или поздно упремся в этот лимит» — вы запредельно оптимистичны, если считаете, что ваша система сообщений проживёт несколько миллионов лет. Даже огромный твиттер не стал заморачиваться и посчитал, что он проживёт не более чем 69 лет

Я бы сказал, что UUIDv7 решает все упомянутые проблемы, однако в нём тоже зашито ограничение на две тысячи лет, чего недостаточно для вышеупомянутой оптимистичности ¯\(ツ)/¯

@Thony Используйте BIGINT или UUID. Ваши проблемы надуманные.

я бы на вашем месте не о теоретических переполнениях инт64 в счетчике сообщений во время когда этой системой будут пользоваться ваши правнуки волновался, а о том, как удобнее структурировать таблицы в остальных аспектах. У нас например хранятся сообщения бизнеса и клиентов. Так вот изначальная реализация была сделана таковой что сообщения ссылаются на диалог через dialog_id, а на практике составной ключ b_id, u_id окажется более продуктивным позволив партицировать все диалоги одного бизнес клиента в одну партицию.

головной болью будет у вас не исчерпание инта-бигинта, а исчерпание места на диске, и вообще сопутствующие проблемы, когда таблица подрастет, а вы тут внезапно решите ее изменить а там уже 500гб.

В целом, если вам кажется возможным, хранить воображаемый лимит INT64 сообщений, то есть 2^64-1 строк таблицы, то учите, что для хранения только строк с ID (8 байт) вам потребуется 16 эксабайт места, или в более часто встречающихся единицах - почти 16.8 млн терабайт дискового пространства, и это будут только ид строк. Так что в лимит диска вы упретесь до этого момента очень и очень много раз, и врядли какое либо партицирвование и шардирование вас спасет.

@teran «Так вот изначальная реализация была сделана таковой что сообщения ссылаются на диалог через dialog_id, а на практике составной ключ b_id, u_id окажется более продуктивным позволив партицировать все диалоги одного бизнес клиента в одну партицию.»‎ - Не до конца понял вашу мысль. Можете развить? Я реализую что-то типа мессенджера, поэтому на первый взгляд хранить диалоги пользователей по dialog_id кажется верным решением.

речь про кейс, когда разные бизнесы общаются с клиентами. Ссыль из сообщений по dialog_id не позволяет партициировать таблицу удобно. Если в сообщениях будет пара business_id, user_id то партицирование по business_id условному, даст нам то, что бизнес-пользователь просматривая диалоги будет работать только с одной партицией своей. В случае с dialog_id данные будут тянуться со всех партиций.
Но это частный случай предметной области, приведенный как, пример, о каких нюансах надо задуматься вместо ид инкрементальных
